# Why is the regular expression not matching the last part of the string?

Tags: .net, regex

Why does this regular expression:

```
Summary:(\r\n\t\t\/\/     (.+))+
```

not match the last line of the following string? *(NOTE the whitespace at the beginning of each line is two tab characters but has been converted to all spaces, at least in my browser--it's correct in edit mode, though.)*  Shouldn't the `+` quantifier cause the part of the pattern in the outer-most parens to match the last line too?

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Do absolutely nothing and don't do anything else other than to do nothing at
        //     all.
```

Here's the result on http://regexstorm.net/tester:

[image]

Comment: Probably it is again the line endings. Use `\r?\n`

Comment: I tried that on regexstorm and it worked

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please elaborate?  Your suggestion worked, but why?  All the line endings are definitely \r\n, I just confirmed.

Comment: @rory.ap Yes, I see. The problem with .NET regexps is that `.` matches a CR symbol, too. `.` does not match `\n` only (by default). So, the inner, nested `(.+)` grabbed the CR and does not give it back. `Summary:(\r\n\t\t// {5}([^\r\n]+))+` also works.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks @WiktorStribiżew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. Look what is happening:

- `Summary:` is matched first
- `(\r\n\t\t//     (.+))+` - at Iteration 1, it grabs `"\r\n\t\t//     Do absolutely nothing and don't do anything else other than to do nothing at\r"` (pay attention at the last `\r`, `.` in a .NET regex, by default, matches a CR symbol)
- The `+` quantifier signals the regex engine to try and match the substring to the right of the current match, i.e. `"\n\t\t//     all."`. It cannot match it as it starts with `\n`. The pattern should expand like `"\r\n\t\t//     (.+)\r\n\t\t//     (.+)"` and so on, i.e. `\r\n\t\t//     (.+)(?:\r\n\t\t//     (.+))*`, but it [does not turn on backtracking with `(.+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Summary%3a%5cr%5cn%5ct%5ct%2f%2f+++++%28.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%5ct%5ct%2f%2f+++++%28.%2b%29%29*&i=%09%09%2f%2f%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+Summary%3a%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+++++Do+absolutely+nothing+and+donothing+at%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+++++all.). Indeed, the regex engine has a way to re-match the string differently as `.+` qualifies for backtracking, but somehow **the `.` that matches a CR does not want to give it back**.

The workaround is to either match the first `\r` as an optional symbol:

```
Summary:(\r?\n\t\t//     (.+))+
```

Or, just match any chars but CR and LF with `[^\r\n]+` (this will ensure cleaner values in the Group 2 capture stack):

```
Summary:(\r\n\t\t//     ([^\r\n]+))+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Summary%3a%28%5cr%5cn%5ct%5ct%2f%2f+++++%28%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29%29%2b&i=%09%09%2f%2f%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+Summary%3a%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+++++Do+absolutely+nothing+and+donothing+at%0d%0a%09%09%2f%2f+++++all.).

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that what we likely want to have here is an expression to pass new lines, such as maybe this one:

```
Summary:([\s\S]*)
```

or

```
Summary:([\w\W]*)
```

or

```
Summary:([\d\D]*)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/i4He0U/1)

[image]

Comment: `[\S\s]` is equivalent to `.` with "single-line" mode on.